# Issue with webADF 931 application migrated to 10 environment within IE8

Tags: arcgis-server

I am currently in process of migrating a webADF 931 application to Arc 10 environment and testing it within IE8. I am having this issue, the map when launched only covers partial area. I have tried setting various sizes but didn’t made any difference. I have atatched the screenshot here. if you see the area on the right and bottom these aren't filled.

Thanks and look forward to any feedback. 
Jay 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the Internet Explorer compatibility meta tag: X-UA-Compatible

Microsoft's own explanation of this tag: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

In your case try simply adding
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">` to the header section of your page.

Comment: Hi Philip, Thank you so very much for your quick reply. I have already added the meta tag in page header. This had resolved the issue with some of the menu items but it didn't fix the issue map extent problem. This seems like an issue with WebADF10 map control. My existing 931 website shows OK in IE8 browser. There must be something else going on here. Thanks jay

Comment: As a point of clarification: are you using the .NET Web ADF or the Java Web ADF? Are you porting a custom application, a customized 'out of the box' web mapping application, or a stock web mapping application?

Comment: Hi Philip, It's a .NET webADF appl. It's a customized application that I am trying to port to WebADF10 environment. I have used the migration utility. I have also posted some details on ESRI forum, Here is the link: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/28846-Issue-webADF-931-application-migrated-to-10-environment-within-IE8?p=97627#post97627. Thanks Jay

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like it could be a CSS issue, though it is a bit surprising that you didn't have any issues at 9.3.1 version of ADF.  in your CSS for the map control are you explicitly stating width and height?  JUst a thought, but to debug if you are using percentages I would switch over to pixels or points just to see if you get a change and this could be your issue.  If changing pixel dimensions does not change your map control size you can be relatively certain your issue is not with css.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have tried changing the % to px. By changing the values, I did find some change in behavior, the area becomes bigger. The map is still not in coordination with rest of the page. I have tried these settings: 640/480, 1280/1024, 1024/768. it doesn't seem right. I also wanted to mention that I migrated this application from 931 to WebADF 10 via migration utility. Looking for more feedback. Thanks jay

Comment: My markup:         <div id="Map_Panel" style="width: 512px; height: 512px; position: absolute;
            top: 0px; left: 260px; overflow: hidden;">
            <esri:Map ID="Map1" runat="server" MapResourceManager="MapResourceManager1"
                Height="480px" Width="640px" PrimaryMapResource="Western Canada" >
            </esri:Map>
        </div>

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a CSS reset.  Can't hurt at this point. IE has weird margin and padding issues.

http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/